# Website build by Prestashop and mobile payment page of PayPal

Tags: mobile, paypal, prestashop

I have a website built by Prestashop. I use PayPal and the template integral_evolution_payment.tpl. When the user goes to the payment page in mobile environment the layout of the page is too small. The buttons and the labels are very small almost unreadable.
How can I customize the page for mobile?
Thank you
Paolo

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Module should have a css folder inside module folder at `css` or `views/css`. Look for it and modify css styles to accomplish what you need. Sometimes if structure has many changes between desktop and mobile version modules could use a different TPL for each version. Anyway this TPLs should be in module `views/templates` folder.

Good luck.